# What if you just want to export a certain commit’s changes? Or just one folder? What if you wanted to make an archive of the repository for backup?

Tags: git, zip

```
git archive HEAD --format=zip > archive.zip
```

> fatal: Unknown archive format '='

can you solve for me?

Answer (score 0):

You have a wrong order of options.

```
git archive --format=zip  HEAD
```

see  [this documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-archive)